# PHP check if Database contains string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Array with data, and I am looping through the data.

For each string, I want to check if it is present in the database (whole table). It might be there inside another string (so if the table contains heyredcat, and you check for red, it also returns true).

I've came up with this sample script, but I can't come up with a MySQL query, Googling resulted in many great suggestions for "if column equals string" but not for a string in the whole table.

```
<?php 
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
foreach ($colors as $value)
   {
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where $value ...... ") or die(mysql_error());
      if($result){
        echo "Color" .$value. "is present";
      else {
        echo "Color" .$value. "is not present";
      }
   }
?>
```

What MySQL query should I use? Also, I'm wonding, is this an efficient way to do this? (time consuming)

Comment: tssss bad edit.
Anyway, hopefully my whole database searching script will help somebody else.
BOUH you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the query can look like:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM `products` WHERE
    `col1` LIKE '%" . $value . "%'
    OR `col2` LIKE '%" . $value . "%'
    OR `col3` LIKE '%" . $value . "%'
    .. etc
");
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);
if ($num === 0) { // not found
```

**But** keep in mind that this is susceptible to SQL injection if the list of colors can be picked by a user.

So you will want to do:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM `products` WHERE
    `col1` LIKE '%" . $value . "%'
    OR `col2` LIKE '%" . $value . "%'
    OR `col3` LIKE '%" . $value . "%'
    .. etc
");
```

You *can* dynamically generate the column names by looking at the mysql schema. The cheaty way would be to do a `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1` first to get all the column names.

---

Even better is to use the `PDO` driver which has a better (less error prone) way of inserting parameters into queries.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer (& edits). It works great, good you mentioned the real_escape, I'd almost forget. Only note is that your method requires a column, and I prefer to search the whole table

Comment: "For each string, I want to check if it is present in the database (whole database)."

Comment: I meant table instead of whole database btw (I'll edit right away), but indeed @Loic this answer does not involve this.

Comment: Bedankt @Frits van Campen, je was de eerste.

Comment: Can't believe this is the good answer while being so resteined to one only example. sniff. Shame on you guys!

Comment: @Loic Your answer is a little rough around the edges, but it's also good.

Comment: What "also"? you can't do better dude, this is THE answer to any mysql db search you could need. self esteem appart.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the whole database then you are doing it wrong.

Here are the main lines on how to do it :

First gather all database tables and columns :

```
Select table_schema, table_name, column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS where table_schema=[your_db_name] and table_name=[your_table_name]
```

You just got the whole database server columns.

Now, you'll need to check, for each column if it's like your string.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    mysqli_select_db($row['table_schema']);
    $res = mysqli_query('select * from '.$row['table_name'].' where '.$row['column_name'].' like "%'.$your_string.'%"');
    while($res_line = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         var_dump($res_line);
     }
}

?>
```

Oh, I'm not responsible for any db lags :D

And you might want to add the table_schema, table_name, and column_name in your dump, I won't take all the fun, have some.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Especially for integrating my request to search the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

you will also need a list of every table in your database to loop through, and every column in every table to query.  I am not aware of a query that can query every column in every table in a database.  Maybe you would be better off using mysqldump and grep?